# Rails Console Acting Up for Model.last Type Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been doing a lot of work in my `console` for this app and it just started acting strangely.  There are a number of weird behaviors, but the one that is most irritating is that when I type in `Joke.last` to try to get the most recently-inputted `joke` from my app, it gives me the joke with `id: 1`.

Has anyone experienced this?  I have tried restarting my server and my console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the SQL output of `Joke.last`? You might have a re-defined default order, which take precedence over the `order by id desc` added by `.last` method.

Comment: The output is `Joke Load (4.2ms)  SELECT  "jokes".* FROM "jokes"  ORDER BY rank ASC LIMIT 1`.  Is that from the model? I didn't know that could override the console like that...

Comment: Yep! Console is nothing but a REPL inside your app. In other words, there's no real difference from where you run your requests (console or by a request on a server), they all are real.